# In Realm is there a way to just map a field to a object?

Tags: java, android, realm

My API currently just returns all objects with no object nesting and just gives us id's to each other object.  So I'll have a parent object with a childId and there is already a Child object saved in Realm.  Is there an easy to way map the childId to the Child object?  Right now I have a pretty big method manually building the relationship after each network call by running a realm transaction that queries the child object and sets it on the parent.

Comment: No, not right now, but it is something we have considered adding to at least the JSON import parts of the API.

Comment: `by running a realm transaction that queries the child object and sets it on the parent.` that's what I do and it works